# JSON::ParserError on trying to run Flutter Project on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, cocoapods

So I am new to mac. I installed Flutter, Android Studio, XCode, CocoaPods (with `sudo gem install cocoapods`) and every other required packages. The app ran successfully on Android but I get this error while trying to run on iOS:

```
JSON::ParserError - Failed to parse JSON at file: '~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/a/d/d/GoogleMaps/6.0.0/GoogleMaps.podspec.json'.

    unexpected token at '"SwiftExample/GoogleMapsSwiftDemos/Swift/AppDelegate.s'
```

This (seems like the most important) part of the long error log. (Check [this issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12115) for the full log).

**I tried:** flutter clean, reinstalling Cocoapods, tried using VPN as suggested in the issue above, none worked.

Answer (score 0):

So, as the error log suggested, there's an issue with the json file (it's incomplete).

The plan was then to make Cocoapods redownload the folder (and the files therein).

Using Finder:

Open Finder, then press Shift + Command + G, and paste the path (to the JSON's parent folder) `~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/a/d/d/GoogleMaps` (GoogleMaps in this case), into the dialog box, then press Enter. This will take you directly to the directory. Rename the directory to say `GoogleMaps_Old` (I couldn't delete it) and run `sudo gem install cocoapods` again. It should download the folders again. Then try to run the project again.

This worked for me.